# Observable collection without INotifyProperChanged for one way binding

Tags: wpf, silverlight, observablecollection

For Silverlight or WPF when control is bound to Observable collection , and I am only interested in collection additions/deletions to be reflected in a control - i.e. one way binding - am I right in thinking that there is no need for INotifyPropertyChanged in a class the collection is comprised of. But changes to the existing element of collection won't be reflected in user interface in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand you well, yes you can have items that don't implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in an `ObservableCollection`. Any list control bound to the collection will be correctly updated in terms of items added/removed, but any changes in any of your items' properties won't be reflected to the UI.